# Как форматировать строку в 2 целых числа?

Tags: python, python-3.x

На ввод подаётся строка "283 + 5621".
Как разбить строку на 2 целых числа - 283 и 5621. Любых, которые будут введены, например "32 + 679"
И заставить интерпретатор сложить эти 2 целых, или даже дробных числа?
Операция может быть любой, вычитание, деление и т.д.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import operator

possible_operators = {'+': operator.add}  # добавляйте другие операторы, если надо

operation = '283 + 5621'
splitted_operation = operation.split()

operand_1 = int(splitted_operation[0])
operator = splitted_operation[1]
operand_2 = int(splitted_operation[2])

print(possible_operators[operator](operand_1, operand_2))
```

Comment: Спасибо! Рабочий вариант! Но пока вопрошал, додумался до более простого варианта.

Comment: А если введут без пробела?

Comment: @GaloGramma вы можете ответить на собственный вопрос

Comment: @Эникейщик в примере с пробелом

Comment: @вася в примере с пробелом, а напишет без пробела. В вопросе ещё написано "или даже дробных".

Comment: @вася, ваш код рабочий, и вы раньше меня ответили. так что я отмечу ваш ответ. + думаю дать еще свой ответ. возможно кому-то пригодиться более простая реализация.

Answer (score 0):

Нашел вариант попроще.

```
inputString = "2311 + 431"
inputString = inputString.split()
if inputString[1] == "+": 
    print(int(inputString[0]) + int(inputString[1]))
if inputString[1] == "-": 
    print(int(inputString[0]) - int(inputString[1]))
```

Comment: Работает только на сложение целых чисел. А ваши же условия: "Операция может быть любой, вычитание, деление и т.д.", "или даже дробных числа".

Comment: исправил, добавил операцию вычитания. по аналогии можно добавлять другие операции.